# How can I prevent running "Xvfb :10 -ac" if it has already been run before?

Tags: shell-script, process, display, xvfb, amazon-linux

I'm using Amazon Linux.  I'm running an automated script through Jenkins with this command

```
Xvfb :10 -ac
```

However, if this command has already been run before, I get the error ...

```
(EE) 
Fatal server error:
(EE) Server is already active for display 10
    If this server is no longer running, remove /tmp/.X10-lock
    and start again.
(EE)
```

How can I modify the above command to only run if there it was not already invoked before with the given variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the message says, there is a lock file, `/tmp/.X10-lock`.  So modify your script thusly to only execute if the lock does not exist:

```
if [[ ! -f /tmp/.X10-lock ]]; then
    Xvfb :10 -ac
else
    echo "INFO: $(date) - X Server already running" 1>&2
fi
```